# "<Message: title>" needs to have a value for field "id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a Message model, And in it I have `create_user` ForeignKey and `receive_user` ManyToManyField:

```
class Message(models.Model):
    """
    消息
    """
    message_num = models.CharField(default=getMessageNum, max_length=16, help_text="消息") # 注意：message_num 相同，说明是同一次发送

    title = models.CharField(max_length=64, help_text="消息名称")
    content = models.CharField(max_length=1024, help_text="消息内容")

    create_user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="created_messages",help_text="创建者")
    receive_user = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="received_messages", help_text="接受者")


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

When I use the bellow to save a message, I except a exception:

```
try:
    receive_user = User.objects.get(id=user_id)
    message = Message.objects.create(
        title=title,
        content=content,
        create_user=create_user,
        receive_user=receive_user,
    )
    message.save()
except Exception as e:
    raise e
```

I get the exception:

```
"<Message: title>" needs to have a value for field "id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.
```

How to resolve this issue? some friend can help me about this?

Comment: What's happening is you're attempting to assign a many to many relationship before your message object actually exists. Try creating the message before assigning the users to it and it should work

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Django documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

Check code after

> What follows are examples of operations that can be performed using
>   the Python API facilities. Note that if you are using an intermediate
>   model for a many-to-many relationship, some of the related manager’s
>   methods are disabled, so some of these examples won’t work with such
>   models.

My must save parent model first, and only after that you can add m2m values. Check below

```
    receive_user = User.objects.get(id=user_id)
    message = Message.objects.create(
        title=title,
        content=content,
        create_user=create_user,
        # receive_user=receive_user,
    )
    # message.save() - no needs in save() when you use create() method
    message.receive_user.add(receive_user)
```

Comment: What purpose does the try / except block serve?

Comment: just copied from the question

Answer (score 2):

Another way to get around with creating a relation to another model while creating it, is to relate to the model by `ParentalManyToManyField` .

With this its possible to save simultaneously the id of the instance and relate to another model.

from modelcluster.fields import ParentalManyToManyField

receive_user = ParentalManyToManyField(User, related_name="received_messages", help_text="接受者")

Maybe this could help.

Comment: Can you link to `ParentalManytoManyField` in the Django docs pls?

Comment: I just saw that the ParentalManytoManyField is a variant of the standard django ManyToManyField. 
The ParentalManytoManyField correlates to Wagtail CMS. Didn't recognize it.