# Many-to-many relationship generating value error on api post request

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to send a post request to database and I get this error:

> ValueError: "<Item: x>" needs to have a value for field "id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.

Here are my models

```
class Farmers(models.Model):
    
    First_Name = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    Last_Name = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    code =models.IntegerField(default=1)
    phone = PhoneField(blank=True, help_text='Contact phone number')
    

class Item(models.Model):

    category = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    amount_in_KG = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    price = models.FloatField()
    farmer = models.ManyToManyField(
        Farmers
    )
    slug = models.SlugField(default=sluger)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(blank=True)
```

here are the the serializers

```
class ItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = ['id','category', 'amount_in_KG', 'price','farmer']


class FarmerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Farmers
        fields = ['id','First_Name', 'Last_Name','code']
```

here are the viewsets

```
@api_view(['POST',])
def api_create_item_view(request):
    
    item = Item()


    if request.method == "POST":

        

        serializer=ItemSerializer(item ,data=request.data)#data is gonna get changed
        data = {}
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            data["success"] = "create successful"
            return Response(data=data)
        return Response(serializer.errors ,status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

I tried to send the request using python requests with the following data

```
post_data={"item":"x","amount_in_KG":"6", "farmer":[1]}
```

I googled the solution is to save item model before farmer is added but I found that confusing in my case.

I'm new to `django` `restframework` and API requests so please help me out.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your problem happens because you can't create two things at the same time, with your case your parent must be saved first - which is item -, so `django` can use its ID to link it with another **exsting** framer ID through `M2M` relationship.

I have included some examples dealing with `M2M` in `create` method at `serializer`.

see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47706988/4984493) answer.
and read this [article](https://www.vinta.com.br/blog/2018/django-rest-framework-read-write-serializers/)