# Override Save Model Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I would like to override the save model in Django, to ensure a check that my User doesn't follow himself/herself. I know I can do this using serializer and put a check in view but I want to learn how to override def save.

```
class Followable(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    followers = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="users", null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.user != self.followers:
            return ValidationError("User cannot follow oneself.")
        
        super(Followable, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I tried printing out *args and **kwargs but it is empty. Also, User is my custom User Model.

**Edit 1:**

I get this error:

```
"<Follow: Follow object (None)>" needs to have a value for field "id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.
```

Full Traceback Error:

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/socialuser/follow/add/

Django Version: 4.0
Python Version: 3.8.10
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'rest_framework',
 'rest_framework_simplejwt',
 'core',
 'authentication',
 'socialuser']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\suyas\.virtualenvs\Memestagram-Tno8CPgV\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\suyas\.virtualenvs\Memestagram-Tno8CPgV\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\suyas\.virtualenvs\Memestagram-Tno8CPgV\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 622, in wrapper
    return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\suyas\.virtualenvs\Memestagram-Tno8CPgV\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 130, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\suyas\.virtualenvs\Memestagram-Tno8CPgV\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py", line 56, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\suyas\.virtualenvs\Memestagram-Tno8CPgV\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py", line 236, in inner
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\suyas\.virtualenvs\Memestagram-Tno8CPgV\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 1670, in add_view
    return self.changeform_view(request, None, form_url, extra_context)
  File "C:\Users\suyas\.virtualenvs\Memestagram-Tno8CPgV\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 43, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\suyas\.virtualenvs\Memestagram-Tno8CPgV\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 130, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\suyas\.virtualenvs\Memestagram-Tno8CPgV\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 1549, in changeform_view
    return self._changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)
  File "C:\Users\suyas\.virtualenvs\Memestagram-Tno8CPgV\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 1599, in _changeform_view
    self.save_model(request, new_object, form, not add)
  File "C:\Users\suyas\.virtualenvs\Memestagram-Tno8CPgV\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 1108, in save_model
    obj.save()
  File "C:\Users\suyas\Desktop\Memestagram\core\behaviours.py", line 34, in save
    if self.user not in self.followers.all():
  File "C:\Users\suyas\.virtualenvs\Memestagram-Tno8CPgV\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py", line 536, in __get__
    return self.related_manager_cls(instance)
  File "C:\Users\suyas\.virtualenvs\Memestagram-Tno8CPgV\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py", line 851, in __init__
    raise ValueError('"%r" needs to have a value for field "%s" before '

Exception Type: ValueError at /admin/socialuser/follow/add/
Exception Value: "<Follow: Follow object (None)>" needs to have a value for field "id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.
```

Comment: `if self.followers.filter(user_id=self.user_id).exists()`?

Comment: Are you trying to compare the request user with the followers or existing user ?

Comment: @Ahtisham I am trying to create a check so that the field user to whom the follower list belong is not able to follow oneself (i.e. add oneself to many to many followers relationship) as it would not make sense.

Comment: You must save parent model first, and only after that you can use/add m2m values. This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47706988/8961170

Comment: can you also tell us, what exactly you are doing when you are getting this error, like are you using django admin to add or something else?

Comment: Notice that `null has no effect on ManyToManyField.`

Comment: Take this scenario: existing user is A and followers of A are B & C. Now if i try to add user A to followers of A it should raise exception ?

Comment: @Ahtisham Yeah I am trying to prevent this scenario.

Comment: @alirezafnatica Okay I understand it now. Thank You Very Much... So, I will have to implement a check in the serializer itself...